# How to pass custom security in spring contract testing?

Tags: java, spring-test

I am trying to use spring contract, this is my contract file:

```
package contracts
import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
  request {
       method POST()
       url '/v1/wallet'
       body("{\n" +
            "      \"externalRefType\":\"BIKER\",\n" +
            "      \"externalRefId\":\"9977633951\"\n" +
            "    }")
       headers {
            header 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            header 'Authorization': 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzeXN0ZW0iLCJ0eXBlIjoic3lzdGVtIn0.ITL-gCOBAzgnMWcCHl4ztywLDKZxNgRbXzSfSWzT72wWoKqPr_PLLET3qFUd_cfRRZZMavjMxyz8_Uqin4j2-A'
    }
}
response {
    status 200
    body("{\n" +
            "    \"walletId\": 135\n" +
            "}")
}
}
```

The Base class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = WalletServiceApplication.class)
public class BaseWallet {

   @Autowired
   private WalletController walletController;

@Before
public void setup() {
    RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(walletController);
}}
```

WalletServiceApplication class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableSnappboxSecurity
@EnableSnappboxClientSecurity
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class WalletServiceApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(WalletServiceApplication.class, args);
          }}
```

and finally WalletController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/v1/wallet")
public class WalletController {

      @Secured(SYSTEM)
      @PostMapping
      public ResponseEntity<?> createWallet(@Valid @RequestBody WalletCreateRequest walletParams) {
           LOGGER.debug(walletParams.toString());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(new WalletCreatedResponse(135), OK);
}}
```

But It does not passed and when I deploy it I get the following error:

> Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 10.964
>   sec <<< FAILURE! - in
>   org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.tests.ContractVerifierTest
>   validate_createWalletContract(org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.tes
>   ts.ContractVerifierTest)  Time elapsed: 0.347 sec  <<< ERROR!
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException:
>   An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: I just have tried example from github, and have add spring-security. It works correctly. Looks like some configuration problem. Do you have your project source on github ?

Comment: No It is not an opensource project, Thank you